# Why the @Transactional annotation not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions

When i developing a spring-boot project, i tried to check if the @transaction annotation really works by insert duplicate items to the same collection, and then i found  something i can't solve.

The dependencies of this project as follows:

- MongoDB Server 7.0
- spring-boot-starter-parent 3.2.4
- mongodb-driver-sync 5.0
- mongodb-driver-core 5.0

---

The snippet code for MongoTransactionManager :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    @Value("${mongo.db}")
    String database;

    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager mongoTransactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory){
        MongoTransactionManager manager = new MongoTransactionManager(mongoDatabaseFactory, TransactionOptions.builder()
                .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
                .readConcern(ReadConcern.LOCAL)
                .writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
                .build());
        manager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return manager;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

The snippet code for Insert:

```
@Transactional
    public void insertMany(String collectionName,
                    ClientSession session,
                    List<Document> documentList,
                    InsertManyOptions options,
                    Boolean verbose) {

        if (Objects.isNull(options)){
            options = new InsertManyOptions();
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = collectionMap.get(collectionName);
        
        {
            collection.insertMany(documentList, options);
            collection.insertMany(documentList.subList(0,100), options);
        }
        
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (verbose)
            log.info("Collections.insertMany, collection name: {}, size: {}, Time: {}ms", collectionName, documentList.size(), (endTime - startTime));
    }
```

---

the expected result of running function **insertMany**  is none of the document in the documentList should be inserted to database successfully due to the second **insertMany** operation would throw an exception, but the result is the first insertMany operation inserted into collection successfully.

the DEBUG logs are:

```
org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Connection checked out: address=localhost:8989, driver-generated ID=5, duration=0 ms
org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command "insert" started on database "form" using a connection with driver-generated ID 5 and server-generated ID 3477 to localhost:8989. The request ID is 9 and the operation ID is 8. Command: {"insert": "single_write_collection", "ordered": true, "txnNumber": 1, "$db": "form", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1711116306, "i": 2}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "8UzN5xZ0TKmfyIn/lvz8Dg==", "subType": "04"}}}, "documents": [{"_id": {"$oid": "65fd90131cc0173f10682826"}, "task_id": "task_round-0index-0", "template_id": "template_round-0index-0", "tree_id": "tree_round-0index-0", "object_field_0": {"task_id": "task_round-0index-0", "template_id": "template_round-0index-0", "tree_id": "tree_round-0index-0"}, "array_field_0": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], "int_field_1": 0, "float_field": 1.0, "date_field_": {"$date": "2024-03-22T22:05:06.335Z"}, "null_field_": null, "true_field_": true, "false_field_": false}, {"_id": {"$oid": "65fd90131cc0173f10682826"}, "task_id": "task_round-0index-0", "template_id": "template_round-0index-0", "tree_id": "tr ...
org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command "insert" succeeded on database "form" in 724.7474 ms using a connection with driver-generated ID 5 and server-generated ID 3477 to localhost:8989. The request ID is 9 and the operation ID is 8. Command reply: {"n": 1, "electionId": {"$oid": "7fffffff0000000000000005"}, "opTime": {"ts": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1711116307, "i": 501}}, "t": 5}, "writeErrors": [{"index": 1, "code": 11000, "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: form.single_write_collection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('65fd90131cc0173f10682826') }", "keyPattern": {"_id": 1}, "keyValue": {"_id": {"$oid": "65fd90131cc0173f10682826"}}}], "ok": 1.0, "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1711116307, "i": 502}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1711116307, "i": 501}}}
org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Connection checked in: address=localhost:8989, driver-generated ID=5
o.s.d.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager    : Initiating transaction rollback
o.s.d.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager    : About to abort transaction for session [ClientSessionImpl@5d3f8661 id = {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "IDoVFI7YQjOiN/7gPUGufw==", "subType": "04"}}}, causallyConsistent = true, txActive = true, txNumber = 1, closed = false, clusterTime = null].
o.s.d.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager    : About to release Session [ClientSessionImpl@5d3f8661 id = {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "IDoVFI7YQjOiN/7gPUGufw==", "subType": "04"}}}, causallyConsistent = true, txActive = false, txNumber = 1, closed = false, clusterTime = null] after transaction.
```

**as you can see, the insert operation returned the errmsg E11000 duplicate key error collection**,
**and the transaction initialized and released normally.**

the possible reasons are:

- not using the replication mode
- version compatibility problem
- not enable the right transaction mechanism for mongoDB

I have carefully investigated all the possible issues above, and currently, as far as I am aware, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong.

**Why the transaction rollback mechanism not working and how can i get the expected result.

Thank you!**